# The intersection 'xxx & xxx' was reduced to 'never' because property 'xxx' has conflicting types in some constituents

Tags: typescript

I got an error while using ts generics, here is the simple code:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCDyAjAVtA3tAvgWAFCkhgCUlUMd9wo4SV0s88AXATwAcBTOAVwEsQAJgEFEILgF44paAB8apANzN2XIhzZheAJxFjok2qjmxDS3Ms7QAKgFkwbfejwBIRH0EAuHv2GiOZ5y11TS0vNQ1tXX88TDMLLitIAGsrFUckjhYAewAzazs2OMpCa2SAHitoDgAPJg4AOwEYRIgUlQA+J1xnYCz6iCYtbmAmLK0AChdnNm5RXmBoVk4vKwAaKZm5haYwLQBzDiYVgoBtKwBdde7p2ZB56AgsgFsOAH0spgALDi1XgTAdl4wPUWC4AJT0CgUPC8ep1LQ5MDALhCEa8PoVKq1BpNUqtVKcTpoFw1DjAbh1cY7VorcpWdpgrwANyyvAEZmh+D6A28glRTHR9S8-MFZQARG4fGLOpJid1SeTKRDyFdYnhev0mNBwiERX1hWiMWKghEtNLHHLnAqKRxxsqsKqihqeUiBX1Xk97F5LScMixoLC8W1OOcDW76mU-e0ORaXJLPLzhIb6ldAsFtGF0zpk47GLgBGTwEFoEzdotkrTWuL4wJzXIWklxSaQtKiq7BR77CdqUkAHRLDjnXvWyk9sEKIA)

On the last line, ts reports the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'Task<"build"> & Task<"repair">' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
   
44 action_map[task.type].execute(task);
```

I try to use switch to avoid errors:

```js
function execute<T extends TaskType>(task: Task<T>) {
    switch (task.type) {
        case "build":
            // now type of `task` should be `Task<"build">`
            BuildAction.execute(task);
            break;
        case "repair":
            // now type of `task` should be `Task<"repair">`
            RepairAction.execute(task);
            break;
        default:
            // now type of `task` should be `Task<never>`
            console.log("Error");
    }
}
```

But it even worse:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Task<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task<"build">'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"build"'.
    Type 'keyof TMap' is not assignable to type '"build"'.
      Type '"repair"' is not assignable to type '"build"'.

50    BuildAction.execute(task);
```

I noticed that vscode's type hint for `task` is always `Task<T>` instead of what I expected.

So, what should I do?

Comment: Here's a valid `Task<TaskType>`: `new Task(Math.random() < 2 ? "build" : "repair", new RObj(), 9)` Is that what you want to support?  If not, then you should first consider changing the type of `task` to be something like `Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">` in the question, so nobody is distracted by the possibility of "cross-term" tasks.

Comment: Assuming you make that change, then you've run into the problem noted at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the fix would be to use generics as shown in [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/Ndoq0w). If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I want to make sure that, without knowing each other, the task's publisher and executor, depending on the task's type, are able to know the type of the task's `target`. For example, when publishing a task, `new Task("build", UnBuildAble, "some data")` is illegal; when executing a task, if `task.type === "repair"`, the executor can determine `target ` is of type `RepairAble`.

Comment: So if you don't want to support `new Task("build", UnBuildAble, "some data")` then you need to change the code in your example, because as I showed you, [your code allows this](https://tsplay.dev/NlvPeW).  Please consider changing the type of `task` from `Task<TaskType>` to `Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">`.  They are not equivalent.

Comment: `Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">` doesn't work. Because the type of the second parameter in the `action_map[task.type].execute` function is `never` when the compiler does not know the exact type of `task.type`. But it solves the problem in `switch`.

Comment: Really a good idea to wrap it in a generic function, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You need to make it `Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">` before you worry about executing the task.  Do you understand that?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to fix it.  If you leave it as `Task<TaskType>` then the answer is "you can't safely execute that and the compiler is right to complain to you"

Comment: A generic wrapper function is what I want. With it, adding new task types and target types doesn't require much modification.

Comment: `Task<TaskType>` is not the type you want; it is a mistake; it allows things that are not executable.  Adding new task types is not in your question as stated.  If you want to add new task types and have them automatically added to the type, this is possible via distributive types like `type SomeTask = { [K in TaskType]: Task<K> }[TaskType];` which evaluates to `type SomeTask = Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">` for your case.  But none of this is relevant to your question. It is a distraction. In order to have your question in an answerable state, you must [edit] the question, or I will do it.

Comment: No problem, I've made the requisite change and posted an answer.  Note that my `SomeTask` definition will be the union you want even if you add more union members to `TaskType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the compiler doesn't have great direct support for dealing with *correlated union types*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Your `task` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
declare var task: Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">;
```

So `task` is either a `Task<"build">` or a `Task<"repair">`. And `action_map[task.type].execute` is therefore also of a union type:

```
const execute = action_map[task.type].execute;
// const execute: ((task: Task<"build">) => void) | ((task: Task<"repair">) => void)
```

Which means `execute` will either accept a `Task<"build">` or it will accept a `Task<"repair">`, but it will not accept both.  Let's imagine we had another task:

```
declare var otherTask: Task<"build"> | Task<"repair">;
```

Clearly it would not be safe to use `execute` to execute that task:

```
execute(otherTask); // error!
```

After all, `otherTask` might be a `Task<"build">` while `execute` might be a `((task: Task<"repair">) => void)`. Well, unfortunately, the types are all the compiler can use to determine whether something is safe or not.  Since `execute(otherTask)` is unsafe, and `task` is of the same union type as `otherTask`, then `execute(task)` is seen as unsafe for the same reason:

```
execute(task); // same error!
```

Of course *we* know that `execute` will accept `task` because they are *correlated* to each other.  But that's because we're tracking the identity of the `task` variable and not just the type.  The compiler can't tell the difference between `execute(otherTask)` and `execute(task)`.  So it worries that they might not be correlated.

The reason why the error mentions the intersection is because the only safe way for a union of functions to be called is to [call it with an intersection of the parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  If `execute` accepts a `Task<"build">` or a `Task<"repair">` but we don't know which, the only safe thing to pass it would be something that's *both* a `Task<"build">` *and* a `Task<"repair">`... hence a `Task<"build"> & Task<"repair">`.  And of course such a thing is impossible; they have conflicting properties, so you get that message about [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

So that's why you're seeing an error.

---

As for fixing it, TypeScript 4.6 introduced some [improvements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#indexed-access-inference-improvements) specifically to address microsoft/TypeScript#30581; you can read about it in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

The recommended approach is to make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.  If `K extends TaskType` is a generic type parameter, the compiler *will* allow you to call a function of type `(task: Task<K>)=>void` with a parameter of type `Task<K>`.  And the improvements in TypeScript 4.6 mean that the compiler will see `action_map[task.type]` as being of type `(task: Task<K>)=>void`:

```
type SomeTask<T extends TaskType = TaskType> = { [K in T]: Task<K> }[T];

function genericExecute<K extends TaskType>(task: SomeTask<K>) {
    action_map[task.type].execute(task); // okay
}
```

The `SomeTask<T>` type is not required by the compiler, but it shows how you can get a union of task types easily.  If `TaskType` contained more union members, `SomeTask` would also gain those members.  And the body of `genericExecute()` is seen as safe.

And luckily you can call `genericExecute(task)` with no problem:

```
genericExecute(task); // okay
```

So that's the recommended approach to such correlated union types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCDyAjAVtA3tAvgWAFCkhgCUlUMd9wo4SV0s88AXATwAcBTOAVwEsQAJgEFEILgF44paAB8apANzN2XIhzZheAJxFjok2qjmxDS3Ms7QAKgFkwbfejwBIRH0EAuHv2GiOZ5y11TS0vNQ1tXX88TDMLLitIAGsrFUckjhYAewAzazs2OMpCa2SAHitoDgAPJg4AOwEYRIgUlQA+J1xnYCz6iCYtbmAmLK0AChdnNm5RXmBoVk4vKwAaKZm5haYwLQBzDiYVgoBtKwBdde7p2ZB56AgsgFsOAH0spgALDi1XgTAdl4wPUWC4AJT0CgUPC8ep1LQ5MDALhCEa8PoVKq1BpNUqtVKcTpoFw1DjAbh1cY7VorcpWdpgrwANyyvAEZmh+D6A28glRTHR9S8-MFZQARG4fGLOpJid1SeTKRDyFdYnhev0mNBwiERX1hWiMWKghEtNLHHLnAqKRxxsqsKqihqeUiBX1Xk97F5LScANLQWF4tqcc4Gt31Mq+9oci0uSWeXnCQ31K6BYLaMLpnTJx2Mcy4ARk8BBaBM3aLZJeADKzw4LSSTu5WutdUcrsFHvsJ2pSQAdEsOOdey3orgAPRj6DO5vVMk2rzjKmVoPi+MCaUQ8SdFlsiFyRc92mtcUmkIb-Tb1kCMF4EdL1pgoqFgglstaaAfb5aetHpKr9zrp0cj1ieWbSkUd6fj89aPnmA7QDWLwgZUNR1I0zTJASEhBlhMr0H6Ab1NYoYrlGWBnOcZg5Nw9TJtABz1D88wAKKzoqHCRliaG4vWuH3kk1a1iBUbKi47bup6bDdsk-YqEOd49rBuAUAxTHAKxc6UopCjQBOH5JGAoK4EAA)