# Create object from another object with the same type but taking less properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object with nested objects in typescript. And I want to copy this object to another object but remain only the part of properties in nested objects.
Here is the code.

Interfaces:

```
enum fname {
  f1 = "f1",
  f2 = "f2",
}
interface Icommon<G> {
  value: G;
  label?: string;
}
interface Itext extends Icommon<string> {
}
interface Ibool extends Icommon<boolean> {
}
interface IForm {
  [fname.f1]: Itext;
  [fname.f2]: Ibool;
}
```

The object from which I want create a new one:

```
const itemFull = {
  f1: {
    value: "hello",
    label: "text label"
  },
  f2: {
    value: false,
    label: "bool label"
  }
}
```

The loop and creating new object:

```
const itemShort = {} as IForm;
let key: keyof typeof itemFull;
for (key in itemFull) {
  const insKey = itemFull[key];
  if (insKey !== undefined) {
    itemShort[key] = {
      value: insKey.value
    };
  }
}
```

Inside this lines of code:

```
    itemShort[key] = {
      value: insKey.value
    };
```

I get an error from typescript:

```
Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

I suppose, the problem is that value can be as bool or as string and TS can't make the match. But still can't manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You have type error, since the `insKey` can be `Itext` or `Ibool` and TS is unable to handle this and you can solve this by using type assertion.

**EXAMPLE**

```
const itemShort = {} as IForm;
let key: keyof typeof itemFull;
for (key in itemFull) {
  const insKey = itemFull[key] as Icommon<unknown>; 
  if (insKey !== undefined) {
    itemShort[key] = {
      value: insKey.value as typeof itemShort[typeof key]['value'],
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This very similar problem as in [The intersection 'xxx & xxx' was reduced to 'never' because property 'xxx' has conflicting types in some constituents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72321759/the-intersection-xxx-xxx-was-reduced-to-never-because-property-xxx-has-c)

In your case, workaround is to create helper function or use `Reflect.set`

```
function assignShortItem<K extends keyof IForm>(x: IForm, k: K, v: IForm[K]) {
  x[k] = v
}
// use
   assignShortItem(itemShort, key,  {value: x}) // ok
```

Working [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.0-beta#code/KYOwrgtgBAZiCGFhQN4CgqwIxQLxQCIYsCAaDWAJj0JkrIpgGYaimGBfNAFwE8AHZFACSAYwD2ECOJAAeAOIA+GukwA3eABswwAFxR5Abgqb4AI2CaA-PoDO3AE4BLEAHNjXPoJHdgAD24aMUlpOXtnN2UeAWRhM3FxTSCJKRlZeMTgeBAo6O9hcGh8YNS5QosHKJdfBxh4UViAMXEHaFUoAG04RGAAOmIAXX1hXwDjTC6EJH7KIZEMzXHO7unmOYLIDzQ0AHodqAAVAAtkcTMAK2BRQJgHSSgAdyOnUSORR+zA0Qcs3yh4KAgYAPKAyPTbCQgexQJy+CCNMCaTTDZqtFSMLD6drqLQ6fQEE5I8QMTCYUwWZGEUaBcmWAgUDjkTB0LEUHHaPSwLS2YBM0m0ykEBZQAX0zCMxhMVmkqAaDn6JiKvlk8yWfHC0UMtBcPaHE4ihL8f4gAAmUG+vxcrkBwNBFyu3F02xgYBA1ycMn+tlsTlcIAAykcWtwRsAILIANJQfy+U22KAAa2AvHEMBEqIgigAFH4US0IKRE-oI4W1HnWh0IwMAJSoCh+DoJgY0NTaiEyaGwsOB4MqDhe9P54yaYCBJO8fTj1NQLzAadd+GIxZoGAtKBZ8cwkAwuEIpG19qQztQiPJmgLveaRvJgZLJxprMuWyn3hQACEuHwrpNwBgLmAJoHmy5odoEfjnieya9HKOgDsIGYdLO07jgMHQEDBwAEAMwFHoEABe55wj2DjcNevDYTKABKv4jtcvQ8twj5EUGJGFuOhYoBh+h+Bw1bAfA3q+gGLEhnCTHdiJbHJoWqBcVAPF8TKC7EaRKHojK7J4vJwEcEsXAcEAA)

Comment: This works and has clear logic! Thanks, a lot, you saved my brain!