# Correlated Union Types from Optional object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, union-types

The following example snippet in TypeScript maps values of an array `arr` to types contained in `Mappings`, using a `mapper` object which contains transformer functions for each `arr` item: ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=0&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhwHkzAJYHsB2BDANgHgBUAaKAaSggA9gIMATAZygGsIQ0AzKAgPigF4oCALYpghEqT4AyKAAUsAJ1S48clAGNmEsjx4BuAFCGNmBsChLFAqAG0ARBzRp7JewEYATK6gAWTwC6lkymGOZGhqCQUACyWGBgKBgA5kyCAN5QTmgAXFAARs44EFgYbl72eRgArsL5EIok-nnmiknJUAC%20EVHQcQkNAIKKqXjkVDT0TAAUvZyWiooAlLY1dQ0BfBmGULtQAG55pEQ7eyhVtfWKht0mZhbC8ZCKeXCIyOjY%20Omnu7bkSSgs3AEHmVhWayuAQCeWmuViTyGIwYYx4SwEfH6iRSDH%20ARubmy9i2UB%20eyyzlhmX2JBQXXR-D4%20wAdMUUsAABZQADUUDpfF8J3JHm8VIOtPpGKgADlLg1pvt0byUEK9s0gdSJZ0GXwAAYAEnS%2006hpQnV1J06xlC5igiggDDQOH2ECxDRsYwo1FojBYbHmcy4jwGih401YICOJHhbsUw1GUh1UGDz1sEYCAH5mXClhEAPR5haKZnB6YKpMphq2fYBabU%20m5qB5gBUUAAoos0IoAIRQZt54xWEvxMs0vlJ%202O52uxGKBUkTV8hv6IA))

```js
const arr = ["foo", "12", 42] as const;

type Mappings = { foo: boolean, "12": number, 42: string };

type MapperArgs<K extends (typeof arr)[number]> = {
    v: K,
    i: number
};
const mapper: {
    [K in (typeof arr)[number]]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K]
} = {
    foo: ({ v, i }) => v.length + i > 4,
    "12": ({ v, i }) => Number(v) + i,
    42: ({ v, i }) => `${v}${i}`,
}
```

To run `mapper` over all items, the usual `arr.map` won't work as expected:

```js
arr.map((v) => mapper[v]({ v })); /* TS error 2345: ... intersection was reduced to 'never' because ... has conflicting types in some constituents */
```

Apparently, this is because of [TypeScripts limitations regarding correlated union types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72326483/8545205). It is possible to use a generic function to work around the issue:

```js
const resolveMapper = <K extends keyof typeof mapper>(key: K, o: MapperArgs<K>) => mapper[key](o);
arr.map((v, i) => resolveMapper(v, { v, i })); // ok ✅
```

However, this won't work after making some mappings optional:

```js
type SetOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;
// ...
const mapper: SetOptional<{
    [K in (typeof arr)[number]]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K]
}, "foo"> = /* ... */

const resolveMapper = <K extends keyof typeof mapper>(key: K, o: MapperArgs<K>) => mapper[key]?.(o); /* not ok ❌ */
```

Is there a way to solve this problem without suppressing the error or using type assertions/`any`?

Comment: TS isn't fully type safe with this stuff no matter what you do, but the closest you're going to get is to apply `SetOptional` to your base type to make a new base type, and then map over *that*, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvoA4w). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thx for the help again, but it looks like your implementation changes the type signature of `mapper` a bit. Now `foo` could be `() => undefined` and this would pass. Also, the optional chaining in `resolveMapper` is inferred to be unnecessary because TypeScript believes `mapper[key]` is non-nullish (this is of course wrong). Looks like this might not be possible the way I want it :/

Comment: • `() => undefined` is just what you get for TS not really caring about the difference between undefined-but-present and missing. This shouldn't matter *too* much, because `mapper.foo?.()` might well be `undefined` anyway. I understand you're not jazzed about that but that feels very minor to me. • I agree that not needing the optional chain is a type safety hole. I'm pretty sure that it got opened when fixing [ms/TS#47890](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47890). I could imagine opening it as a bug report? But that being said, this is still the closest you can get.

Comment: (see prev comment) Should I write up an answer saying that this is the closest you can get to having TS verify the correctness of what you're doing, along with the caveat about the non-nullish hole?  Presumably it's still less bad than using type assertions or `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to dealing with correlated unions (see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)) as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) only works when the operations and types are in a particular form.  You have to have some "base" object type, and then write things as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that base type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of that base type.

Your `Mappings` is a reasonable base object type, and `{ [K in (typeof arr)[number]]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K] }` is a mapped type over `keyof Mappings` (I'm not sure why you're using `(typeof arr)[number]` instead of `keyof Mappings`, but I'm not going to delve into that...  I'll just use the equivalent type `{ [K in keyof Mappings]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K] }`.

But when you wrap it in `SetOptional<⋯, "foo">` it is no longer a mapped type. It's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of mapped types, each piece of which deals differently with a different set of properties.  The only reason `{ [K in keyof Mappings]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K] }` works is because the compiler can "see" that for generic `K`, indexing with `K` gives the single generic function type `(o: MapperArgs<K>) => Mappings[K]`. Try that with `SetOptional<⋯, "foo">` and you'll get some weird intersection thing that the compiler can't evaluate without knowing what `K` is.

---

The closest you can get to making this work is to apply `SetOptional` to `Mappings` to get a new base type, and then map over that instead.  It could look like this:

```
type PartMappings = SetOptional<Mappings, "foo">;

const mapper: {
    [K in keyof PartMappings]: (o: MapperArgs<K>) => PartMappings[K]
} = {
    foo: ({ v, i }) => v.length + i > 4,
    "12": ({ v, i }) => Number(v) + i,
    42: ({ v, i }) => `${v}${i}`,
}

const resolveMapper = <K extends keyof typeof mapper>(
    key: K, o: MapperArgs<K>) => mapper[key]?.(o)
//  const resolveMapper: <K extends "foo" | "12" | 42>(
//  key: K, o: MapperArgs<K>) => PartMappings[K]
```

Now the compiler sees that the return type of `resolveMapper` is `PartMappings[K]`, which is accurate.

---

Notice that I said it's the closest you can get. It's not fully type safe.  For watever reason, `(typeof Mapper)[K]` is not seen as possibly nullish, so you can write the incorrect code `mapper[key](o)` in your function instead of `mapper[key]?.(o)` and not get an error. This is unfortunate, but it seems to be part of how ms/TS#47109 was implemented.  One might consider filing a bug report about it, but even if it is determined to be a bug, the approach in ms/TS#47109 is not a panacea. TypeScript isn't fully type safe in general, and neither is ms/TS#47109 in particular; see [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730).

So when considering whether or not to refactor to this code, the bar is, for better or worse, not "does this refactoring make the type checking fully accurate", but just "does it make it *more accurate* than it would be with alternatives like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)" (and of course where you weigh risks of false positives to false negatives according to your use cases.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UGGAD0kcWRwwJy1Or1Bv9nhNw3NTCCLSCUAAPlB6bmCyknVGY5a3VAPf6vcCfayoe8YaQ4YY4yclJcoH1FFgQHhxs8m2VGnMoDds24gsFwjPBWEPkYu3j7d9uRjfYndfrDRvEUzRaDQfkOkA)